# How can I make jQuery Beauty Tip stay open, even when i click elsewhere?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use jQuery Beauty Tip as a "context menu". I want to open the beauty tip manually, and close it manually.

I use the `trigger: 'none'` option:

```
$('#example15').bt({
  trigger: 'none',
  contentSelector: "$('#example-15-content')",
  width: 400
});
```

But when I click outside the Beauty Tip, it hides.

How can I stop it from hiding, and use `$('#example15').btOff()` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [`clickAnywhereToClose` option](http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/jquery.bt.js) (scroll to bottom) that defaults to `true`, just set it to `false`, like this:

```
$('#example15').bt({
  trigger: 'none',
  contentSelector: "$('#example-15-content')",
  width: 400,
  clickAnywhereToClose: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`clickAnywhereToClose` sounds like the option you're looking for:

```
    clickAnywhereToClose: true,     // clicking anywhere outside of the tip will close it
```